# Polygonal Laso Zoom

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections, zoom

Is there a setting i have to pick for zooming in and out with the mouse scroll while making a selection with the Polygonal Laso Tool in photoshop? Tried with 3 versions  of photoshop and only one works

Comment: Does holding Alt while using the mouse scroll wheel not work for you? What does "only one works" mean? You're able to scroll in and out with one version of Photoshop but not the others? Maybe try resetting your Photoshop preferences to default in the versions that do not work.

Comment: Yes while using polygonal lasso the alt+scroll zoom doesn't work on my pc from home  (photoshop 2018 and photoshop 2020), at work i have photoshop 2020 but the alt+zoom works just fine while making a lasso selection

Comment: Did you try resetting your Photoshop preferences to default for the computer that doesn't work?